# how to get current time zone city name like America/Los_Angeles

Tags: c++, c, linux

I tried strftime, which has %z and %Z, but these are outputs like +0800 and PST.  I'd like to get the longer name like America/Los_Angeles.  Is there a function call to do this?

Comment: Are those names standardized somewhere, or is that just how those names are presented on various platforms?

Comment: There is not a function call to do this.  On Most Unix-like systems, the answer can be found by inspecting the target of the symbolic link `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: I think so.  Linux has a list of them in /usr/share/zoneinfo.  it's supposed to be coded in the file /etc/localtime, so the last resort is to read and parse that, but there must be an api to get it.

Comment: @SteveSummit prob is sometimes it's not a link.  sometimes people copy from /usr/share/zoneinfo over to change the time zone.

Comment: IANA provides its "Time Zone Database" at https://www.iana.org/time-zones

However, that might not meet your requirements, as the time zone name per that IANA database is "Americas/Los_Angeles" and not "US/Los_Angeles".  Looking at the data on my Ubuntu 20.04 install under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, there does appear to be enough information there to extract what you need.  I'm not aware of any standardized function that does so, however.

Comment: seems like the only solution is to download the IANA db and build a map from %z or %Z to there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle my mistake.  I meant America/Los_Angeles.  I fixed the description now.

Comment: @thang You can build that map, but it won't be unique.  There are several different definitions of `EST`, for example.  (And, yes, I understand about the problem of `/etc/localtime` sometimes not being a symbolic link.)

Comment: @thang For example, last time I checked, there were 31 different zones that all used the abbreviation (that is, a `%Z` value) of "CST", and 24 "EST".

Comment: Here is a brief article on building that map using the C++20 chrono preview library: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#convert_by_timezone_abbreviation

Comment: @SteveSummit map is definitely not 1-1.  I just need 1, so i can probably just pick the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not a standard way to do this until C++20, and even then only the latest MSVC has implemented it to date (gcc is getting close).

In C++20 there is a type [`std::chrono::time_zone`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.timezone) which has a member function called `name()` which will return a `string` such as "America/Los_Angeles".

It might be used like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    zoned_time local_now{"America/Los_Angeles", system_clock::now()};
    cout << local_now << " " << local_now.get_time_zone()->name() << '\n';
}
```

Which just output for me:

```
2022-12-31 07:34:41.482431 PST America/Los_Angeles
```

Or if your computer's local time zone is currently set to "America/Los_Angeles", then the `zoned_time` construction could look like this instead:

```
    zoned_time local_now{current_zone(), system_clock::now()};
```

If all you want is the time zone name, and not the current time, this can be further simplified to just:

```
cout << current_zone()->name() << '\n';
```

Prior to C++20 the only way I'm aware of to get functionality like this is to use my free, open-source [C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which will work with C++11/14/17.

Answer (score 1):

One way — I must admit, a decidedly imperfect way — is to read the symbolic link `/etc/localtime`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define LOCALTIME "/etc/localtime"

int main()
{
    char buf[100];
    int r = readlink(LOCALTIME, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
    if(r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't read link %s: %s\n", LOCALTIME, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[r] = '\0';
    char *name = buf;

    char *p1 = strstr(buf, "zone");
    if(p1 != NULL) {
        char *p2;
        p2 = strstr(p1 + 1, "zone");
        if(p2 != NULL) p1 = p2;
        p2 = strchr(p1, '/');
        if(p2 != NULL)
            name = p2 + 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

This will work on most Unix-like systems, including Linux and MacOS.  It will not work on Windows, which AFAIK does not use the IANA tz database at all.  It will not work on systems where `/etc/localtime` is a file, rather than a symbolic link to one of the zoneinfo files.

If `/etc/localtime` is a file, there is no good way to determine which zone name it represents.  I believe you would have to compare it to all of the files underneath `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, looking for matching contents.

I'm not sure what magic technique Howard uses in [his C++ solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74970414/how-to-get-current-time-zone-city-name-like-america-los-angeles/74970559#74970559).
(But I mean no disrespect with that word "magic".)

Comment: Here is how my `current_zone()` function does it on non-Windows systems: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/src/tz.cpp#L3931-L4057  It follows this basic idea, but is much more complicated due to idiosyncrasies on the various platforms.