Very bizarre: tzlocal.get_localzone() different output based on python3 aliasing?
I just noticed this, I'm completely puzzled so as to why it happens, and how I can prevent it.
The computer I work on is Windows 10, and is set up in city Copenhagen. My platform is this:
$ for ix in "uname -s" "python3 --version"; do echo "$ix: " $($ix); done
uname -s:  MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045
python3 --version:  Python 3.11.9

Since I use a bash terminal under MINGW64, I have also an alias set up for python3 in .bashrc:
alias python3="winpty python3"

OK; so now I want to print tzlocal.get_localzone(), by calling a python3 command in the bash terminal:
$ python3 -c 'import tzlocal; print(tzlocal.get_localzone())'
Europe/Copenhagen

Excellent, I got exactly the time zone as expected. However, recall python3 here is actually winpty python3; to test just python3, let's prepend a backslash to the command, to escape the bash aliasing:
$ \python3 -c 'import tzlocal; print(tzlocal.get_localzone())'
Europe/Paris

Amazing - I never would have expected this; why on earth do I get Paris here, and not Copenhagen (which is what Windows 10 itself on that machine is set up for)?
I mean, it's not that far off, as far as timezones go - but why settle for less, when there are obviously conditions that make it output the correct time zone?
So, why does this happen - and how can I get \python3 run of tzlocal.get_localzone() also return Europe/Copenhagen?

EDIT: by printing os.environ in both cases, can see that the winpty python environment defines an environment variable 'TZ': 'Europe/Copenhagen' - while the direct python environment has no such variable.

See also: https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/8414

Some background: Windows and IANA do not use the same timezone identifiers in their timezone databases. tzlocal gives you IANA identifiers. So when you're on Windows, you need a mapping between those two timezone db systems. This is error-prone since there is no agreement between IANA and MS that this should be unambiguous (see also the timezone tag wiki, sect. "Time Zone Databases"). tzlocal relies on a community effort for this.
On Windows, if I set the tz to Copenhagen, Windows uses "Romance Standard Time" internally (at the moment; 2024-04-18). You can check that by running tzutil /g in a terminal. If you check the XML file I linked above, the first mapping is... "Europe/Paris". "Europe/Copenhagen" is also listed lower down. Those two timezones follow the same rules AFAIK, so the mapping is "OK" (correct in terms of UTC offset), but not perfect.
As to why you're getting different results; I think you've provided the explanation in "printing os.environ in both cases, can see that the winpty python environment defines an environment variable 'TZ': 'Europe/Copenhagen'". tzlocal looks for the TZ environment variable. If that is set to a IANA db identifier, it will return it since that is actually more reliable than the Windows tz mapping described above.

Excellent, thanks a ton for this answer, it is really great to know the background for such issues, that I don't really deal with daily, but end up surprising me anyways ...

Btw, Re: "no agreement between IANA and MS" - I found https://stackoverflow.com/q/74970414/ "There is not a standard way to do this until C++20, and even then only the latest MSVC has implemented it to date (gcc is getting close). In C++20 there is a type std::chrono::time_zone which has a member function called name() which will return a string such as "America/Los_Angeles"." - I tried compiling the program there with MSVC, and got "Europe/Copenhagen", so maybe there's hope for IANA and MS interop.

@sdbbs My experience with C++ is very limited but on first sight, it seems chrono ships with the IANA db. That's a common thing to do for timezone libraries, to be platform-independent and control the version of the db. Rust's chrono-tz crate does the same thing, Go's time package also. The trouble always starts when you want to obtain the current tz of a system, i.e. when you need to call some OS API.
